# govalidator ValidateMap validate map of array

Tags: validation, go

I want to validate my input map of array with govalidator.ValidateMap.

Please can someone suggest for Sample mapTemplate for map of array.
Please find below the code snippet.

Thanks in Advance

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/asaskevich/govalidator"
)

func main() {

    var mapTemplate = map[string]interface{}{
        "name":       "required,alpha",
        "categories": []interface{}{",alpha"}, //error: map validator has to be either map[string]interface{} or string; got []interface {}
    }

    var inputMap = map[string]interface{}{
        "name":       "Prabhu",
        "categories": []interface{}{"category1", "category2"},
    }

    result, err := govalidator.ValidateMap(inputMap, mapTemplate)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error: " + err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("result : %v\n", result)
    for _, v := range inputMap["categories"].([]interface{}) {
        fmt.Printf("category : %v\n", v)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems validation of slices has not yet been implemented. There is no check in the `What to contribute` list for slices/arrays.

You can however use the function `ValidateArray` to iterate over a slice and validate its members.

```golang
govalidator.ValidateArray(inputMap["categories"], func(val interface{}, i int) bool {
    valStr, ok := val.(string)
    if !ok {
        return false
    }
    return govalidator.IsAlpha(valStr)
})
```

Comment: I'm however a bit troubled by the naming that package has chosen, talking about `arrays` all the time when they mean `slices`. That does not invoke a lot of trust.

Comment: Thanks for response.
I want to do ValidateMap for map of array. not separately.

Comment: As I said in the in my answer: The README of the package states, that this is not implemented yet.  See for youself: https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator#what-to-contribute. There is no check next to the array related stuff.

Comment: It might be implemented soon, though, as the latest commits seem to be regarding array integration.

Comment: curl -X POST 'http://127.0.0.1:3482/validation' -d '{"client_id": -1, "categories":["category1", "category2"]}' . I want to validate my API input request.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want. Won't change the fact, that it is not yet supported by the library, as the error tells you as well.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Please can you let me know any alternative in your mind.

Comment: You mean other validator packages? I don't use any. You can check if you find any here https://awesome-go.com/ or here https://go.dev/